# docker running a data container from scratch

Tags: docker

I created a data only container containing static HTML files that are intended to be consumed by a nginx container. Goal is that my webapp is providing a volume that nginx can use.

For this reason I created a simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
MAINTAINER me <me@me.com>
ADD dist/ /webappp/
```

When I run the created container from command line `run -d -v /webappp --name webapp myOrg/webapp echo yo`

I get the error `Error response from daemon: Cannot start container db7fd5cd40d76311f8776b1710b4fe6d66284fe75253a806e281cd8ae5169637: exec: "echo": executable file not found in $PATH` which if of course correct because the image has no commands at all the can be executed. Running a container without a command is not possible.

While this error on command line is not a big problem for me because I know the data container is still created and can now be accessed by nginx it turns out to be a no go if I want to automate it with Vagrant. The automated processes always fail because of this error.

My only solution so far is to extend my little handy image from from a distro which IMHO doesn't make sense for a data only container in order just to call echo or true!

Is there a NOP exec command in docker or does docker need always to execute something, is it possible to run a scratch container that does nothing or does not produce an error.

Comment: I am not sure if this help but have you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845785/most-appropriate-container-for-a-data-only-container ?

By the way, I ended up using busybox for my data container.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the Docker manual: The container don't need to be running. It also doesn't say that the container "should" be able to run at all.

So instead of echoing something stupid by running a data only container e.g. `docker run -v /webappp --name webapp myOrg/webapp echo yo`

It is already enough to **just create** the container and never run/start it.

`docker create -v /webappp --name webapp myOrg/webapp`

Note to self: Vagrant does not support docker create when provisioning!

Comment: Great answer! Note that in docker 1.5.0 I had to append a command to run for `docker create` to work. Of course, the command doesn't have to exist, since the container will never run.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using scratch?

Just use the nginx image as a base. You already have the image cached so it won't take up any more space and you'll be able to call echo.

Some references for data containers:

- [Data-only container madness](http://container42.com/2014/11/18/data-only-container-madness/)
- [Understanding Volumes in Docker](http://container-solutions.com/2014/12/understanding-volumes-docker/)
- [Offiical docs on data containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)

Comment: You are right about the size! But I don't want to have any overhead (figuratively speaking). One day someone might start the data only container because he might be tempted to think "Hey" this is nginx by reading its name. It will even work but for sure not with the nginx config you wanted to. Because no one took and will take care updating the data only from image and having it in sync with the working nginx config. So to me this is just a workaround for a workaround by just as using busybox or any other mini distro.

Comment: Well, no because I don't think you can override the echo command with `docker start`. Incidentally, this is a good reason to put a description of the container inside the echo command as it will show up on docker ps and inspect.