# Using docker image to store data files

Tags: image, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

I am new to docker and have just started exploring it. What I am trying to achieve is to publish a Docker image, which would just have some configuration files. These files would be shared across multiple projects.

**So the image I want to publish is 'my-config-image'.**

---

**This is how the directory structure is:**

```
/my-config-settings
     /folder1/multiple files
     /folder2/multiple files
     file1.txt
     file2.txt
```

---

After reading online and going through the docker quick start I have got some understanding.

I decided to use Create a simple base image using `scratch`.
referred from (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/)

**This is how my Dockerfile looks.**

```
FROM scratch
ADD folder1 / folder2 /
```

This is the command I am using to publish an image.

```
/my-config-settings/docker build -t my-config-image .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.12 kB
Step 1 : FROM scratch
 ---> 
Step 2 : ADD folder1 / folder2 /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cc9c3f338f51
Successfully built cc9c3f338f51
```

When I want to check if the image was created locally I am confirming it in this way by executing

```
docker images


REPOSITORY                                          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
my-config-image                                     latest              cc9c3f338f51        2 minutes ago       39 B
```

My main query is how can I check if this is working, Also did this add the file1.txt and file2.txt into the image, if not how do I specify to add these files in the image.

Is there a way I can add all the files and directories recursively into the image I am trying to create?

Also how to I access this image, means how can I check if this image actually has all the folders and files. Is there a way to cd into this?

I am okay with suggestions and looking at another docker approach, if what I am trying to do doesn't make sense.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused to be honest. Are you asking how to put a folder into another folder? Or are you asking how to know whether it worked? Both? Neither?

Comment: I am trying to create an image with the same folder structure I have shown. I am not sure if the command I used is to refer both folders? If its adding a folder into another folder then my command ADD folder1 / folder2 / is wrong. I am not trying to achieve that.

Comment: Do you know how to run an image?

Comment: `docker run -it my-config-image bash` to see at least what happened because you said you don't know whether or not it worked

Comment: I tried that but I am getting an error. docker: Error response from daemon: Container command 'bash' not found or does not exist..

Comment: sudo docker exec -i -t THE_ID /bin/bash

Comment: THE_ID is it the image id? If yes, then that gives me an error Error response from daemon: No such container: As its an image and not running inside any container I suppose.

Comment: Can you just get your container running using the `-d` switch?

Comment: No, I should have clarified, it is a running container, like one you start with the -d switch. Any command will do (doesn't have to be bash) when you use -d`

Comment: These type of images are often called data-only containers. They have come out of fashion with named volumes, but can still be useful. See also this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845785/most-appropriate-container-for-a-data-only-container

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to address a configuration management problem with an application management approach. For shared configurations, you generally want to take the "centralized location approach". Basic examples of this would be a git repository or an S3 bucket. Both solutions have native document storage and can be appropriately shared between services with fine-grained access control.

A docker image isn't the docker approach to store/share configuration. By having an image, you can basically do two things:
1. Base other images off your initial image
2. Run a container

Given that your image here is just `Scratch` and files, there are no executables and nothing to run. The hello world example copied a directory with an actual script in it, which is why they ended up with a runnable container.

As a base image, configuration doesn't make sense coming before things like dependencies.

If you really want to use a docker tool for this, you're looking for docker volumes. That can persist a file system and is easy to share around different containers.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

Comment: Reputation limit, unfortunately

Comment: I agree, but this is just an test example I am trying to use for my own learning. I want to achieve this using docker images.

Comment: Docker images don't particularly make sense here. I'll update my answer describing why

Comment: I don't necessarily agree in all cases. It can be nice to have this in a change tracked history like what Docker's FS provides... and already where it needs to be.

Comment: Maybe I used a bad example, to say these are configuration files. Just can be any random files or code. But for the image I want to start from scratch. And only add all the files I have in my root directory. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Also how can I access the internal structure of the image? Can I cd into it and check if all files got added?